# How to get history over one epoch after every batch

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am training a model with keras for **one epoch** only:

```
history = model.fit([x], y,
                    validation_split=0.2, epochs=1, batch_size=2)
print(history.history['accuracy'])
```

The history now obviously only contains one value from the end of the epoch. How can I evaluate the training accuracy or loss during the epoch? I expect these to be the values that are shown in the console during training.

To be clear: I want a history to be written after every batch (not after every epoch, as per usual).

Comment: I think you can write your [custom callback](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback#introduction) then every batch it print out the accuracy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save training history on every epoch in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127527/how-to-save-training-history-on-every-epoch-in-keras)

Comment: You rightly expect. What causes you to disappoint?

Comment: Please see my edit. I am interested in history after every batch, not every epoch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to save the accuracy and loss at the end of each batch. To do that you need to create a custom callback as shown below

```
class BCP(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    batch_accuracy = [] # accuracy at given batch
    batch_loss = [] # loss at given batch    
    def __init__(self):
        super(BCP,self).__init__() 
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):                
        BCP.batch_accuracy.append(logs.get('accuracy'))
        BCP.batch_loss.append(logs.get('loss'))
```

now in model.fit include

```
callbacks = [BCP()]
```

now train for 1 epoch. at the end of the epoch the values of the accuracy and loss for each batch is stored in BCP.batch_accuracy and BCP.batch_loss. You can print them out
as follows:

```
print('{0:^4s}{1:^22s}{2:^10s}'.format('Batch', 'Loss', 'Accuracy'))
for i in range (len(BCP.batch_accuracy)):
    print('{0:^4s}{1:15.5f}{2:15.2f}'.format(str(i), BCP.batch_loss[i], BCP.batch_accuracy[i]* 100))
```

Comment: There is something wrong in this. If I rerun model.fit several times it keeps appending to the callback lists.

Comment: you need to re instantiate the callback each time before you run model.fit